# Error on posting data to server

Tags: php

when i am trying to post the data i am getting the same error many times like undefined variable. i don't where is the error and even the data is not getting posted to database. i hope you will help to solve this error. if there are modifications please let me know.

**File.php**

```
<form action="/create" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">

<div class="form">
    <h3>Lead Information</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="desig" placeholder="Designation"/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>
    <input type="text" name="telephone"placeholder="telephone"/>
    <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/>
    <input type="text" name="linkedin"placeholder="Linked In">
    <select name="priority">
      <option >Priority</option>
      <option >TBD</option>
      <option >Hot</option>
      <option >Warm</option>
      <option>Cold</option>
      <option>Dead</option>
    </select>
    <select name="leadsta">
      <option >Lead Status</option>
      <option >Attempt to Contact</option>
      <option >Contact in Future</option>
      <option>Contacted</option>
      <option>Engaged in dialogue</option>
      <option>Junk Lead</option>
      <option>Lost Lead</option>
      <option>Not Contacted</option>
      <option>prequalified</option>
    </select>
<input type="text" name="skype"placeholder="Skype">
</div>
<div class="form">
        <h3>Company Information</h3>
        <input type="text" name="cname"placeholder="Comapny Name"/>
        <input type="url" name="website"placeholder="Website"/>
        <input type="text" name="domain"placeholder="Domain"/>
        <input type="text" name="anualrev"placeholder="Annual Revenue"/>
        <input type="text" name="nemp"placeholder="No. of Employess"/>
        <input type="text" name="street"placeholder="Street"/>
        <input type="text" name="city"placeholder="City">
        <input type="text" name="state"placeholder="State">
        <input type="text" name="zip"placeholder="Zipcode">
        <input type="text" name="country"placeholder="Country">
        <input type="text" name="gdesc"placeholder="General Description">
    <input type="text" name="cskype"placeholder="Skype">
    <br>

  <button input type="submit" name="submit"value="Add">Submit</button>

      </form>
    </div>
```

**Contoller**

```
 <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use DB;
   use App\Http\Requests;


 class crmcontroller extends Controller
{
  public function addleads(){
   return view('forms.leads.add');
 }
  public function insert(Request $request){
  $name = $request->input('forms.leads.add');
  DB::insert('insert into leadlist (fname,lname,$desig,email,telephone,mobile,linkedin,priority,ledsta,skype,cname,website,domain,anualrev,nemp,street,city,state,zip,country,gdesc,cskype) values(?)',[$fname,$lname,$desig,$email,$telephone,$mobile,$linkedin,$priority,$ledsta,$skype,$cname,$website,$domain,$anualrev,$nemp,$street,$city,$state,$zip,$country,$gdesc,$cskype]);
echo "Record inserted successfully.<br/>";
echo '<a href="/insert">Click Here</a> to go back.';
 }
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('leadsadd','crmcontroller@addleads');
Route::post('create','crmcontroller@insert');
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRhjp.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help and finally i got a solution few days ago.
In this i have changed controller function Insert to this then it's working.

```
public function insert(Request $request){

    DB::table("leadlist")->insert([
      "fname"=>$_POST["fname"],
      "lname"=>$_POST["lname"],
       and so on

      "cskype"=>$_POST["cskype"]
  ]);
  echo "Record inserted successfully<br>";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use Models to insert/update/delete data to/from database.
2. The request contains your form data so you should use it:

   ```
   $fname = $request->input('fname');
   $lname = $request->input('lname');
   ```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. How can i make Models for insert/update/delete can you please help me with that